# Keep a picture in a correct rotation in all web browsers

Tags: css

I have been thinking how to solve my problem where some of my pictures on my website are in the right/correct position in some web browsers, like Firefox and safari, while they are rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise in other browsers such as IE and chrome. I cannot find any tips and tricks to solve this problem on the internet, and therefore I try to ask this question here.

Here is a link to the webpage where the problem occurs:
www.waxholmspartiet.se/kontakt.php

Comment: You need to use `-webkit-transform` in Chrome and `-ms-transform` in IE, just `transform` isn't enough. Although I do agree that it would be a much better solution to just upload images in correct orientation instead of trying to rotate them in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

this is your css:

```
.rotate90 {
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);/*Chrome, Opera, Safari*/
    /*-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);/*Mozilla firefox*/
    /*-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /*IE9*/
    /*transform: rotate(90deg);*/

    width: 130px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    image-orientation: 90deg;
}
```

All the rotation transform commented. image-rotation is no css attribute as far as i know.

Also i suggest you to separate rotation from other proerties:

```
.kontaktbild    {
    width: 130px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.rotate90 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

and use in the images you need to rotate:

```
<img class="kontaktbild" src="Brostrom.jpg" alt="Broström">
```

or

```
<img class="kontaktbild rotate90" src="Brostrom.jpg" alt="Broström">
```